# How do I prove that $e^z$ is entire?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, exponential-function

How does one prove that$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}e^z = e^z$, $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$?

**Attempt 1**
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}e^z=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{e^{z+\Delta z}-e^z}{\Delta z} = \lim_{\Delta z\to 0}e^z\frac{e^{\Delta z}-1}{\Delta z}$$
I assume that $\frac{e^{\Delta z}-1}{\Delta z}\to1$, but since $\Delta z$ isn't necessarily real I don't know how to deal with the limit.

**Attempt 2**

I considered using the Cauchy–Riemann equation and it's relation to differentiation to evaluate $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}e^z$ by computing the partial derivatives. Let $f(z)=e^z$.

$$f_x(z) = \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{e^{x+\Delta x+iy}-e^{x+iy}}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to0}e^{x+iy}\frac{e^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}$$
Since $\Delta x\in\mathbb{R}$ this is essentially just a standard limit from calculus since $e^{x+iy}$ is constant and the fraction is real and tends to $1$. So $f_x(z)=e^z$ and I don't know if it's continuous on all of $\mathbb{C}$ but I'll save that one for later. I cannot assume that $f_y(z)=-if_x(z)$ since I would have to assume that $f$ is entire which I have not proven. So I have to compute $f_y(z)$ like I did with $f_x(z)$.
$$f_y(z)=\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{e^{x+i(y+\Delta y)}-e^{x+iy}}{\Delta y} = \lim_{\Delta y\to0}e^{x+iy}\frac{e^{i\Delta y}-1}{\Delta y}$$
Here I run into a problem again because of $e^{i\Delta y}$ and I don't know how to compute that limit.

Eulers formula would possibly make things a bit more simple, it usually does, the reason I didn't want to attempt to apply it is because I have not seen a proof of it that is rigorous that I understand. I have seen the Maclaurin series proof but I am not familiar with complex power series and convergence must be proven. Anyway, this post is getting to be a bit too long for such a simple result, but there you have my attempts. Now please help me. How do I prove this?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler's_Formula for a collection of proofs, not all of which use power series

Comment: If you try to avoid the Euler formula, then you are trying to calculate the derivative of a function you never defined. Which explains why you don't get anywhere...

Comment: @N.S. Many proofs of eulers formula use the derivative of $e^z$ and that's what I want to prove and I want to avoid circular proofs.

Comment: Then what is your definition of the complex exponential function if you don't want to use power series and Euler's formula?

Comment: The power series approach is the most rigorous and simple way to do it.

Comment: @Open Ball I have not studied complex power series unfortunately.

Comment: @LeBtz I'll use Eulers formula if I can find a non-circular proof of it.

Comment: @David if you have a reasonable amount of experience in basic real analysis, you can learn everything you need about that in the weekend.

Comment: The problem is you're trying to prove a fact about something that you don't even know how it is defined. Surely you can see that this is not going to work out well.

Comment: @David it's ok if you want to avoid Euler's formula. You just need to tell us what your definition for the complex exponential shall be then.

Comment: @David Check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note** If you don't use the Euler formula, then you didn't define $e^z$ for complex, which explains why you run into so many trouble. Actually, in some sense, the Euler formula is equivalent to what you want to prove:

**Lemma** Let $f(z)$ be a function which is equal to $e^x$ on $\mathbb R$, and which satisfies $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2)$.

Then CR hold everywhere if and only if 
$$f(iy)=\cos(y)+ i \sin(y) \forall y \in \mathbb R$$

**Idea of Proof:** Let $f(iy)=u(y)+iv(y)$. Then
$$f(x+iy)=e^x(u(y)+iv(y))$$
And hence, CR are equivalent to 
$$u=v' \\
 v'=-u$$

This system of ODE is easy to solve and the general solution is 
$$u(y)=C \sin(y) +D \cos (y)\\
v(y)=-C \cos(y) +D \sin (y)$$

Therefore, CR holds if an only if we get the above.

Now, since $1=f(0+i0)=u(0)+iv(0)$ we get $u(0)=1, v(0)=0$ which gives $C=0, D=1$.

Therefore CR hold if and only if 
$$u(y)= \cos (y)\\
v(y)= \sin (y)$$

**QED**

If you ever understood the Euler formula, you can look at the following as a proof of Euler formula: The Lemma Above has the following immediate consequence:

**Consequence:**  $f(x+iy)=e^x(\cos(y) + i \sin(y))$ if the only function which is entire, equal with $e^x$ on $\mathbb R$ and satisfies satisfies $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2)$.

Moreover, this function has the property 
$$f'(z)=f(z)$$

**P.S.** Note that the Euler formula is the definition of the complex exponential. Any proof of the Euler formula is actually a proof that this is the only definition which can work. You can use the following approach if you are concerned about circular logic:

Define $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$
$$f(x+iy)=e^x(\cos(y)+i \sin (y))$$

Then, with definition, you can prove that this $f$ satisfy the following properties
$$f \mbox{ is entire } \\
f(0)=1 \\
f'=f \\
f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2) \\
f(x)=e^x \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

Given these properties, it makes sense to call this function $\exp(z)$.

Comment: What does CR mean?

Comment: @David Cauchy-Riemann